# How to get the median of a row in SPSS?

Tags: spss, median

I have a data in SPSS structured like this:

student_number age study_for q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 (<-- these are columns)

There are students with numbers from 1 to 67. For each of those students I would like to get the median of q1 to q8, how could I do that in SPSS? And then I would like to get a median of that median if possible. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in SPSS. It may not be welcome on StackOverflow either, as it is a "show me the code" question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPSS has a `MEDIAN` function for across columns. It would simply be in your example;

```
COMPUTE MedQ = MEDIAN(Q1 to Q8).
```

After that you can either use `AGGREGATE` or use `FREQUENCY` to get the median of the 67 observations.

Comment: Thanks Andy! Can I use "compute" variables in the same way to get "mode"? 

I've tried Transform -> compute variable and then: modeQ = Mode(Q1 to Q8) but program says it the number of arguments to function is invalid...

Comment: No there is no MODE. See [this NABBLE discussion](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Computing-a-Variable-in-SPSS-Mode-of-Many-Variables-td5713850.html#a5713855) for code on how to generate the MODE across cases. It tends to be a bit hairy because the mode can easily be multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS will always try to find the central tendency of a "variable", right? So, if you really want the median of q1 to q8, then you will need to restructure the data. Go to the "Data" menu and then select "Restructure". Then choose what option fits and compute whatever you want. I think you can use the "Transpose all data" option and save changes in a different data set so that the original data set is not altered. :)